# Text shifting effect bottom to top scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the div inside the fixed div, I want the posts to change when the page is scrolled.

Example: When the page is opened, it says "Lorem" in the div. When the user scrolls the page, "Lorem" should change and the example should be "Ipsum". While this is happening, "Lorem" should slide up and "Ipsum" should come from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the onScroll event

object.addEventListener("scroll", myScript);

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. My knowledge of html and css is limited. I don't have a programming language. Can you show an example of how it's done?

Comment: To do this you need to learn javascript the third part of web development after html and css

Comment: Since I don't have time to learn Javascript, I opened a topic here. Thank you anyway.